# How to remove underline and provide a box around angular material components?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to remove underline and provide a box around different angular components globally with a one-place defined css,i.e, global css.

For example, just to remove underline I tried this, in my common.scss file:

```
 .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
    }
```

But it dosen't work.

I am looking for solutions without the use of ViewEncapsulation and ng-deep.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<mat-form-field appearance="outline">`

Comment: Thanks! But the appearance="outline" doesn't fulfill the requirement. I need a way to customize it. For eg, i don't need a rounded corner box and the hover effects,etc. To do this I will again require a method to override the default styles, which brings us to square one @Ploppy :)

Comment: This type of question is asked quite often, but if you don't want material inputs, why use them in the first place?

Comment: It is not that I am not using material features. Its just that there are some styling that I am trying to modify. Other than that material provides a lot of other features that are quite useful.

Comment: It probably does not work as is because your css rule is not specific enough to have precedence

Comment: I think so this was the problem. Thanks @David.

Comment: Using Angular Material but not using material design is fighting an uphill battle. It can be done, but you'd probably be better off choosing a different UI framework. If the application design does not follow material design, don't use material design components.

Answer (score 1):

Set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the `@Component` parameters
and `display: none;` in the component css
i.e. in the input-box.component.ts file:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-input-box',
    templateUrl: './input-box.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input-box.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and in the input-box.component.css file:

```
.mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}
```